# CopyFromRecordSet text to numeric

Tags: excel, vba, recordset

I'm trying to copy a table using the recordset method but when I paste to excel the numeric data turn into text value. How can I fix it?

```
Function runReport(nome_relatorio As String)

SQL = sqlStatement(nome_relatorio)
titulo = nome_relatorio
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

If Not SQL = "" Then
    Set query_res = Connect_To_SQLServer_Obj(svName(), dbName(), SQL)

    If wb.Worksheets.Count > 10 Then
        MsgBox ("O limite de relatórios foi atingido. Por favor, exclua um relatório gerado para prosseguir.")
    Else
        Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
        ws.Name = wb.Worksheets.Count - 2
        Set rng = ws.Range("B5")
        For i = 0 To query_res.Fields.Count - 1
            rng.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = query_res.Fields(i).Name
        Next i
        rng.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset query_res
    End If

    Call design
    Call Close_Objects

Else
    Exit Function
End If

End Function
```

[image: Error in Excel]

Comment: Screenshot indicates a regional setting where Excel does not recognize comma for decimal separation in numbers. Please [confirm region](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-windows-regional-settings-to-modify-the-appearance-of-some-data-types-edf41006-f6e2-4360-bc1b-30e9e8a54989).

Comment: Also, what does the corresponding SQL console show of these same sample of numbers? Dot or comma separation? Please post SQL query. Are you running any `CAST` or `CONVERT` to render these columns as varchar?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to force the columns in Excel to be formatted as a number if the field is numeric, then you can look at the `.Type` property of the field in the recordset:

```
    For i= 0 To query_res.Fields.Count - 1
        With objXLSheet
            .Cells(1, i+ 1) = query_res.Fields(i).name
            If query_res.Fields(i).Type = 4 Then    '   numeric field
                .Columns(i+ 1).NumberFormat = "0"
            Else
                .Columns(i+ 1).NumberFormat = "@"
            End If
        End With
    Next i
```

Regards,

Comment: I tryed this method and still doing the same conversion to text when I put it in excel. I just refreshed the post with the image of the error.

Comment: Try looping the `.Fields(i).Type` after you have copied from the recordset?

Comment: No. I tryed looping the .Fields(i).Type before the copy from the recorset!

Comment: Well, give it a go and see what happens then - sometimes the order that you do things in is important!!